# Batch copy to multiple locations replacing part of filename

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, batch-rename, cp

Say I have multiple files
`file-replace-1.ext`,`file-replace-2.ext`,...,`file-replace-10.ext` to be copied to locations `~/tree/loc1`,`~/tree/loc2`,...,`~/tree/loc5` replacing the part `replace` with corresponding `loc*`.

I have been using

```
for i in *replace*; do cp "$i" ~/"tree/loc1/${i/replace/loc1}"; done
```

to get it done for just `loc1`. How can I batch copy this way to all the locations?

*Update*

I used `loc1`,`loc2`, etc for simplicity. The code I am looking for should work for any subdirectory name in a parent directory. For example the subdirectory names could be the names of months.

Comment: Quoting prevents bash from expanding `~`. Replace `"~/tree` with `~/"tree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a find command, printing only the directory within the tree structure and incorporating this within within your loop and so:

```
for i in *replace*
do
  find ~/tree -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n" | while read line
  do
     if [[ "$line" != "tree" ]]
     then
       cp "$i" ~/tree/"$line"/"${i/zipped/$line}"
     fi      
  done
done
```

Comment: `$line` needs to be quoted too. After all, it could contain spaces.

Comment: Very true. I have amended.

Comment: This works but I get an error `cp: cannot create regular file '~/tree/tree/fixtreefix.ext':No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have any other directories under tree that you don't want to move files into?

Comment: @Raman Sailopal No. why `$line` takes the value `tree` too and encounters no such file or directory error

Comment: @Raman Sailopal If there is  a directory named `tree` inside `~/tree`, then there is no error

Comment: Its the way %f displays the top level directory in the output. I've added an if statement to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop:

```
for locnum in {1..5}
do
  for i in *replace*; do cp "$i" ~/"tree/loc$locnum/${i/replace/loc$locnum}"; done
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I used `loc1`,`loc2`,etc for simplicity. instead I have the names of the months, January, February etc.

Comment: The idea is the same: You need to loop over your month names.

Comment: How to loop over sub directory names?

Comment: @Praveen????? `for subdirectoryname in subdirectoryname1 subdirectoryname2 ......`

Comment: the subdirectory names are the names of months

Comment: As long as you know where they are located and how they are named, you can write the command in the same way as my solution. Don't see where you have a problem. BTW, the more you edit your question to deviate from the original question, the more it would make sense to write a completely new question which exactly describes the problem, and at which point you are stuck with solving it.

Comment: @Praveen:  Sorry, but this is not **obvious** from the suggestions you already got here: `for subdirectorynameundertreebeingamonth in january february ....`